# jQuery to find all previous elements that match an expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, **how do you match elements that are prior to the current element in the DOM tree?** Using `prevAll()` only matches previous siblings.

eg:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="findme">find this one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="myLinks">find the previous .findme</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="findme">don't find this one</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my specific case, I'll be searching for the *first* `.findme` element prior to the link clicked.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've come up with - hopefully it'll be useful in many different situations. It's 2 extensions to jQuery that I call `prevALL` and `nextALL`. While the standard `prevAll()` matches previous siblings, `prevALL()` matches ALL previous elements all the way up the DOM tree, similarly for `nextAll()` and `nextALL()`.

I'll try to explain it in the comments below:

```
// this is a small helper extension i stole from
// http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/reverse/
// it merely reverses the order of a jQuery set.
$.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};

// create two new functions: prevALL and nextALL. they're very similar, hence this style.
$.each( ['prev', 'next'], function(unusedIndex, name) {
    $.fn[ name + 'ALL' ] = function(matchExpr) {
        // get all the elements in the body, including the body.
        var $all = $('body').find('*').andSelf();

        // slice the $all object according to which way we're looking
        $all = (name == 'prev')
             ? $all.slice(0, $all.index(this)).reverse()
             : $all.slice($all.index(this) + 1)
        ;
        // filter the matches if specified
        if (matchExpr) $all = $all.filter(matchExpr);
        return $all;
    };
});
```

usage:

```
$('.myLinks').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .prevALL('.findme:first')
        .html("You found me!")
    ;

    // set previous nodes to blue
    $(this).prevALL().css('backgroundColor', 'blue');

    // set following nodes to red
    $(this).nextALL().css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

---

*edit* - function rewritten from scratch. I just thought of a much quicker and simpler way to do it. Take a look at the edit history to see my first iteration.

*edit again* - found an easier way to do it!

Comment: Shouldn't this be "nextALL()" in your "set following nodes to red" call?

Comment: Perfect! Worked without a hitch exactly the way I wanted it to! Nice.

Comment: Thanks for this code, solved a problem we had been struggling with for a while! :D

Comment: Just my two cents: I think prevOnWholeDocument / nextOnWholeDocument() would be *much* better names for those functions. They're more descriptive and not terribly long to write, not to mention given that they would only be used here and there (I guess,) so being a little verbose wouldn't hurt much...

Comment: This should probably use `this.context` instead of `$( 'body' )`, so that it works on elements in other documents as well.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are doing this inside an onclick handler so you have access to the element that was clicked.  What I would do is do a prevAll to see if it is at the same level.  If not, then I would do a parent().prevAll() to get the previous siblings of the parent element, then iterate through those backwards, checking their contents for the desired element.  Continue going up the DOM tree until you find what you want or hit the root of the DOM.  This a general algorithm.

If you know that it is inside a table, then you can simply get the row containing the element clicked and iterate backwards through the rows of the table from that row until you find one that contains the element desired.

I don't think there is a way to do it in one (chained) statement.

Comment: great suggestion with the algorithm. I actually implemented it (see the first edit on my answer), but it ran a little slow. What I ended up doing was selecting everything and then slicing that array on either side of the current object, which seems to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: this solution works for both your original problem, the problem you mention in your first comment, and the problem you detail in the comment after that.

```
$('.myLinks').click(function() {
    var findMe = '';

    $(this).parents().each(function() {
        var a = $(this).find('.findme').is('.findme');
        var b = $(this).find('.myLinks').is('.myLinks');
        if (a && b) {                             // look for first parent that
                                                  // contains .findme and .myLinks
            $(this).find('*').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).attr('class');
                if ( name == 'findme') {
                    findMe = $(this);             // set element to last matching
                                                  // .findme
                }
                if ( name == 'myLinks')    {
                    return false;                 // exit from the mess once we find
                                                  // .myLinks
                }
            });
            return false;
        }   
    });
    alert(findMe.text() );               // alerts "find this one"
});
```

this works for your example in the OP as well as a modified example as explained in the comments:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">don't find this one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">find this one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="myLinks">find the previous .findme</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">don't find this one</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

as well as this test case which you added:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">don't find this one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">don't find this one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="findme">find this one</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="#" class="myLinks">find the previous .findme</a>
```

Comment: hey that's not bad! some points though: it doesn't search the siblings of the current node, and since you're searching forwards instead of backwards (like parents()), i guess you'd be wanting to use :last instead of :first. i was probably a bit ambiguous about that in the question

Comment: as long as the .findme is before the actual click, it should work fine in any markup. this specific solution works for your test code. i may be misunderstanding you, but it searches back first (looks through parents) then forward to find .findme

Comment: or do you mean in cases where there are two .findme's before the link, it should match the last one (before the link)?

Comment: yeah :\ sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: points for effort, but it doesn't work sorry. If you put a link after the table, it won't find anything. I've knuckled down and written another solution which I'm just about to write up now...

Answer (score 1):

I usually number elements (1,2,3..) (rel="number"), so then i use this code to give class to all previous elements:

```
var num = $(this).attr("rel");

for (var i = 1; i<=num; i++)
{
    $('.class[rel="'+i+'"]').addClass("newclass");
}
```

Comment: -1 for answering a 2.5 year old question.  If I could, I'd give you another -1 for answering it with a patently 'bad practice' answer.  And I'd give you another -1 for including broken code in that answer.

Comment: knock yourself out :)

2.5 year old question is still a question.

Comment: I disagree with the first reason for your -1, old questions are perfectly good to answer if there is new info/opinions. The other two are ok reasons a negative vote if @John wants to spend his duckets on being negative, but personally I think its a little brutal to come down negative on newbie so hard. Especially when he was clear he is just sharing his way (he didn't say it was the best way).

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, heres what i came up with. my function uses [compareDocumentPosition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_comparedocumentposition.asp). dont know how it compares to the other solutions in terms of performance though.

```
$.fn.findNext = function ( selector ) {
  var found, self = this.get(0);
  $( selector )
    .each( function () {
      if ( self.compareDocumentPosition( this ) === 4 ){ 
        found = this; 
        return false;
      }    
    })
  return $(found);
}
```

of course one could change this quite easily to fetch ALL elements following the calling element.

```
$.fn.nextALL= function ( selector ) {
  var found = [], self = this.get(0);
  $( selector )
    .each( function () {
      if ( self.compareDocumentPosition( this ) === 4 )
        found.push(this);          
    })
  return $(found);
}
```

#### EDIT: streamlined version

```
$.fn.findNext = function( s ){
    var m = this[0], f=function(n){return m.compareDocumentPosition(n)===4;};
    return this.pushStack( $(s).get().filter(f) );
}
```