# lazy load iframe (delay src http call) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, iframe, lazy-loading

I am looking for something similar to [jQuery image lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), but for `iframe`s.

Comment: Best bet is to just not add the iframe to the DOM until you want to load it, no chance of confusion then...

Comment: The iframe is hard coded into the DOM. I don't have the option to manually insert them, otherwise this would've been the easiest route.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
var iframes = $('iframe');

$('button').click(function() {
    iframes.attr('src', function() {
        return $(this).data('src');
    });
});

iframes.attr('data-src', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).removeAttr('src');
    return src;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGDuV/).

Comment: So if `src` is hard coded in html of the DOM, change them to `data-src` then on demand change it to `src` to load the content? Also, my event is not based on scroll, but rather on click that `:target`s the containing `div`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work (see edit above), hence down vote. Got some code that works? Would be happy to give it a try and change my vote and select this as the answer. I do appreciate your response either way and I like the logic behind your explanation. I just want a working solution to be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307518/twitter-bootstrap-iframe-usage) was recently posted specific to iFrames with Twitter Bootstrap-based tabs, which I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307518/twitter-bootstrap-iframe-usage/13309370#13309370) using a technique I'm calling [Lazy Loading of iFrames](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/YbT7r/). The js/jquery is as follows; see the full code including html markup in the fiddle or on my response to the OP:

```
<script>
$('#myTabs').bind('show', function(e) {  

// identify the tab-pane
paneID = $(e.target).attr('href');

// get the value of the custom data attribute to use as the iframe source
src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');

//if the iframe on the selected tab-pane hasn't been loaded yet...
if($(paneID+" iframe").attr("src")=="")
{
    // update the iframe src attribute using the custom data-attribute value
    $(paneID+" iframe").attr("src",src);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**`<iframe loading="lazy"`**

When implemented, this feature will allow lazy loading when the `iframe` enters the viewport without any JavaScript!

There is also an analogous feature for images: [How do you make images load lazily only when they are in the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321907/how-do-you-make-images-load-lazily-only-when-they-are-in-the-viewport/57389607#57389607)

For `iframes`, I'm not sure what is the status, but it does seem like there is an intention to enable it as well:

- caniuse says available: https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element does not mention `loading` currently, while https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element does
- MDN marks it as experimental: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

To observe this in action, open the "Network" tab of your developer tools before running the snippet below. If your browser implements the feature, you can clearly see new network requests as you scroll down to the next iframe!

Test outcomes:

- Chromium 81: works, loads on hover
- Firefox 77: fails, loads all at once

```js
document.getElementById('load-now').addEventListener('click', function(){
  for (const img of document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')) {
    img.loading = 'eager';
  }
});
```

```css
.separator {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
img {
    height: 340px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
#load-now {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="load-now">Click me to load all images now!</div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump"></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama"></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush"></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton"></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_H._W._Bush"></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe loading="lazy" height="340" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Reagan"></iframe></div>
```

**YouTube videos**

For YouTube embedded video `iframe` more specifically: [Lazy Load youtube video from iframe API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856498/lazy-load-youtube-video-from-iframe-api)

On Chromium 81, it also works on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/3p0tk5nc but didn't work here on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure why. Removing the `loading="lazy"` makes no difference, so I think it fails for some other reason.

Keep in mind that embedding YouTube videos on a local HTML file also fails randomly to me which makes testing harder: [Embed Youtube code is not working in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424578/embed-youtube-code-is-not-working-in-html/55661292)

```js
document.getElementById('load-now').addEventListener('click', function(){
  for (const img of document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')) {
    img.loading = 'eager';
  }
});
```

```css
.separator {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
img {
    height: 340px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
  #load-now {
  border: 5px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div id="load-now">Click me to load all images now!</div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/j_fl4xoGTKU" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TQ5k2u25eI8" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FOwYDlay8rI" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MRhAljmHq-o" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wAQxIla7F68" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div><iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_6D05gCWh_I" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></iframe></div>
```

Comment: This seems not to be working on Chrome 91. It's [documented by Google developers though](https://web.dev/iframe-lazy-loading/). Weird

Comment: @Frenchcooc let me know if you find anything. Also worked on Chromium 85, Ubuntu 21.04 just now.

Answer (score 0):

You could always intialize the src attribute to about:blank and then when your click event fires, set the src attribute to the URL you want to navigate to.

Comment: the iframe `src` is hard coded in the HTML of the DOM and don't want to do too many DOM manipulation by replacing it with about:blank and then replacing it back with the URL (which need to be stored as a variable).

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the src to about:blank?  Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/MaUfH/

Comment: The `iframe` is embedded into the HTML of the page and loaded on page load, while your example loads the `iframe` onClick. This doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to do this in WordPress**

Here is an automatic, request reducing, solution

*In WordPress plugin form*

Here is a WordPress plugin you can download and manually install via the WordPress plugin repository. I created this today just to handle this situation. No changes to content are needed, this works automatically once activated on any and all iframes.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lowermedia-iframes-on-demand/