# Using iframe inside tab

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have tab html element each tab contains iframe element.

Here is code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">BBC</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">CNN</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Sky news</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/" height="500px" width="100%" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <iframe src="http://edition.cnn.com/" height="500px" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        <iframe src="http://news.sky.com/" height="500px" width="100%" />    
    </div>           
</div>
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2293/).

But the problem that tab element not works properly when I change between tabs.
Any idea why it's not working when I try to change between tabs?

Comment: iframe must have closing tag : <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/" height="500px" width="100%" ></iframe>

Comment: Nice Devi, post it as an answer.

Comment: check this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307518/twitter-bootstrap-iframe-usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the iframe element isn't a self-closing element. The versions of Firefox and Safari you're using are treating the /> at the end as just > and assuming everything after it is contained within the iframe.

---

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">BBC</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">CNN</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Sky news</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/" height="500px" width="100%" ></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <iframe src="http://edition.cnn.com/" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        <iframe src="http://news.sky.com/" height="500px" width="100%" ></iframe>   
    </div>           
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a note it is better for performance to lazy load the content of Iframe on tab display like: http://jsfiddle.net/r1bausx7/