# Delay loading of html5 video after the rest of the page finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, lazy-loading

I have a video element being used as the background of a section towards the bottom of a page I'm building.  I'm trying to build a sort of 'lazy-load' for it by storing the src as a data-src attribute and using jQuery to apply it to the src attribute after the other assets have loaded (since it's not a hero image or anything, I want to load a poster to save cut load-time and then load the video later). It doesn't seem to be working for me at all.  The src attribute is applied correctly but the video doesn't load or autoplay. Am I approaching this from the wrong angle? Is there a better way to accomplish it?

Building on wordpress.

Basic HTML

```
<video width="100%" loop controls autoplay class="connect-bg">
    <source data-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/contact_Footer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

jQuery Function

```
$(window).load(function(){
    footer_lazyloader();
});

function footer_lazyloader() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    $("video.connect-bg source").each(function(){
        var sourceFile = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $(this).attr('src',sourceFile);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know much PHP, but don't you need a `src` on your `source?  `<source data-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?><u> **" src="** /contact_Footer.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: currently using javascript to grab the url from the 'data-src' attribute and switch the src from a placeholder tiny gif to the video url stored. forgot to add the tinygif placeholder src! :)

Comment: For YouTube videos on-hover: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154958/lazy-load-iframe-delay-src-http-call-with-jquery/62523325#62523325

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can manually trigger the video to load and play by using '.load()' and '.play()' respectively. Target the parent of the 'source' element using 'parentElement' to accomplish this:

```
$(function() {
  $("video.connect-bg source").each(function() {
    var sourceFile = $(this).attr("data-src");
    $(this).attr("src", sourceFile);
    var video = this.parentElement;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  });
});
```

Comment: just a note about easier way to call the data tag `$(this).data('src')` = `$(this).attr('data-src')` but otherwise plus1^^