# Loading video asynchronously

Tags: html, css, wordpress, asynchronous

**What i am trying**

I'm making changes to website and we have a header which is 100vw and 100vh at load.
This header contains a video which acts as a background.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay muted loop="loop" id="header_background_video">
    <source src="<?= $header['achtergrond']['url']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It's a wordpress site and it links to a video which is hosted on the same site.
Whenever we try to speedtest the site through google's tool and gtmetrix we find that the size of the video is giving us a bad rating. The biggest speed problem of all.

**We have tried several things:**

1. Compressing the video even until it is blurry
2. Converting to webm
3. Converting to webm and compressing it.
4. Shorten the video till 5 seconds which is way to short but still
   same problem.

Disabling the autoplay in the html element seems to help but that would completely screw up the header.

**I did research**

after research I found that loading a video asynchronously would fix the problem even the video is on autoplay.
I tried searching for a valid tutorial that works that doesnt contain third party apps like wistia.com but I can't find them.

**My question**
Is their a way to load a video asynchronously?

**EDIT**

I tried to do this but this didn't work.
I adjusted some of the values to the one used on the site.

```
function lazy_load() { ?>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            footer_lazyloader();
        });


        function footer_lazyloader() {
            $(function() {
                $("video#header_background_video source").each(function() {
                    var sourceFile = $(this).attr("data-src");
                    $(this).attr("src", sourceFile);
                    var video = this.parentElement;
                    video.load();
                    video.play();
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'lazy_load');
```

The video html element now looks like

```
<video muted loop="loop" id="header_background_video">
    <source src="<?= $header['achtergrond']['url']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay loading of html5 video after the rest of the page finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033115/delay-loading-of-html5-video-after-the-rest-of-the-page-finished-loading)

Comment: @HowardE I tried to apply your solution as described in the post you linked but it doesnt resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `preload` attribute inside the video tag. It will load the video after the complete page load.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp