# How to lazy load a youtube video embedded on an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, shopify, lazy-loading

How do I apply lazy loading to an `iframe` embedding a video?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/teL-R6yimDY"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen=""
    width="560"
    height="315"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have tried to add `loading="eager"`, `loading="auto"` and `loading="lazyload"`

Comment: use srcdoc property to load a placeholder image which is wrapped by <a> linked to your youtube. this way youtube won't even load if user don't click on the image. something like   the code below:
srcdoc="<style>/*IMAGE-STYLE-HERE*/</style><a href="VIDEO-LINK-HERE"><img src="IMAGE-SOURCE-HERE" ><span>▶</span></a>"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lazy load iframe (delay src http call) with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154958/lazy-load-iframe-delay-src-http-call-with-jquery)

Comment: For me this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856498/lazy-load-youtube-video-from-iframe-api/68296861#68296861

Answer (score 4):

You can use `srcdoc` attribute inside your `iframe` tag to load an image. Please see the following example as reference:

```
<iframe
  width="560"
  height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y8Wp3dafaMQ"
  srcdoc="<style>*{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}</style><a href=https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y8Wp3dafaMQ?autoplay=1><img src=https://img.youtube.com/vi/Y8Wp3dafaMQ/hqdefault.jpg alt='Video The Dark Knight Rises: What Went Wrong? – Wisecrack Edition'><span>▶</span></a>"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen
  title="The Dark Knight Rises: What Went Wrong? – Wisecrack Edition"
></iframe>
```

Source:

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GRKZryx

https://css-tricks.com/lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos/

Comment: This can't be embedded in the page with other content