# Load iframe video as image in Angular

Tags: angular, iframe

YouTube video iframe can be embeded for example this way:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-youtube-video-in-iframe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Basically YouTube embeds drastically reduce page load speeds, especially on mobile. Since we use them on many of our pages this is an issue.

Is there a way to set a screenshot image with a play button in the place of the YouTube embed in Angular, and only load the actual YouTube video when the user clicks it?

Comment: you can use amp for youtube player, or try lazy loading

Comment: I believe this is rather a question related to youtube, i would say using this questions response https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/4217907 
As you suggest make an image placeholder and replace with iframe on click

Comment: I would like to have that solution not only for youtube, it would be nice to have it work with iframe vimeo etc.

Comment: Different media platforms may not have thumbnails available or the url might differ, i believe this needs to be asserted per provider. Maybe switch case in your code to find the thumbnail url based on the video url

Comment: Hmm, ok. What about any solution to just insert any image (not thumbnail). Where you in effect load just a placeholder image,the user then clicks play, and then the content of the iFrame is loaded instead ?
Do you know if that solution is possible? If yes, where can i look for some examples or information how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use srcdoc attribute inside your iframe tag to load an image. Please see the following example as reference:

```
<iframe
  width="560"
  height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y8Wp3dafaMQ"
  srcdoc="<style>*{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}</style><a href=https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y8Wp3dafaMQ?autoplay=1><img src=https://img.youtube.com/vi/Y8Wp3dafaMQ/hqdefault.jpg alt='Video The Dark Knight Rises: What Went Wrong? – Wisecrack Edition'><span>▶</span></a>"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen
  title="The Dark Knight Rises: What Went Wrong? – Wisecrack Edition"
></iframe>
```

Source:

[How to lazy load a youtube video embedded on an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608884/how-to-lazy-load-a-youtube-video-embedded-on-an-iframe)

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GRKZryx

https://css-tricks.com/lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos/

Comment: It works. One more question is there a possibility to add my own class (for example .video) in srcdoc instead {padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}  ?
i mean to have something like this:
<style>*{.video}</style>