# Embed Youtube code is not working in HTML

Tags: html, youtube

I am trying to use embed youtube code in HTML but when I press play button it say "This video is unavailable". I am using the following HTML code for it:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I have tried other embed youtube videos too, still says same thing. I am using Chrome.

[image]

Comment: It may be the owners of the videos you're embedding have disabled embedding.

Comment: It is working, otherwise you would not even see the youtube player.

Comment: yeah, I do see the youtube player, when i try to play the video it says this video is unavailable. I tried so many embed youtube, it cant be that all videos I am choosing disabled embedding by the owners.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same issue recently and it had nothing to do with video owners embedding settings. Apparently **YouTube forbids embedding some videos in a localhost environment** without a public domain, but your video can be embedded with no issue whatsoever through a public domain/subdomain: Replace the src value in the JSFiddle from @PStarczewski's answer with your video link and it will work properly.

Comment: @Pearl Oyun , kindly consider marking my answer as accepted if it qualifies as such , thank you

Comment: Thank you! This helped me identify the issue and I was able to find a more descriptive answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969269/embedded-youtube-video-doesnt-work-on-local-server

Answer (score 26):

For me this was caused by a referrer policy "no-referrer" on my site. Youtube seems to block embedding when no-referrer is set.

Hope to save someone from wasting time with this crap.

Comment: wasn't enough for me

Comment: @VincentAlex I'm sorry to hear that, but I reproduced the referrer thing on multiple servers with different yt sources - and there is no specific error message for - which is kinda misleading. So I think this hint could be useful for someone searching for a reason for "This video is unavailable", although of course there are other possible reasons which could cause the error.

Comment: Found the answer, we must access the html file via a domain name, not locally C:/. Youtube has a domain white listing.

Comment: @VincentAlex Not really, can you please check this link https://www.youtube.com/embed/6CerdjvePsg there is no other domain its youtube's embed url event if its not playing this video. But playing in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CerdjvePsg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This was the correct fix in my case. I was running helmet on a nodejs server and it sets the referrer policy to "no-referrer" by default, causing some videos to show the "Video is unavailable" message.

Comment: How do you changed the policy in the iframe?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes you could try <iframe referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">

Comment: Thanks, I have used `referrerpolicy="origin"` and also changed the src to always match the pattern `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/${code}` and it is working now even in localhost

Answer (score 21):

**TL;DR**

> Youtube allows only https pages to stream with embeds/iframes.

> Make sure that embeds are allowed by the video owner.

> Set a less restrictive referrer policy such as ["no-referrer-when-downgrade"](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-no-referrer-when-downgrade)  in order to allow youtube to know the origin of the request. In django you can do this by adding following line in `settings.py`

```py
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

**Long read:**

If you are facing this in django application recently, it could because of the recent change in referrer policy in django 3. Read more [here](https://chipcullen.com/django-3-referrer-policy-change/)

When you add an iframe for a youtube video (**given that the video owner allows embeds**), the referrer (the host origin where the video is being played) is sent to youtube, by the scripts inside the iframe (the embed url gets a new page which brings all the required scripts). If the server is setting a referrer policy which prevents the communication about the referrer, youtube rejects the play request and responds with 204 - no content.

Starting from django v3.x, the referrer policy is set to ["same-origin"](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-same-origin) by default which is too restrictive to let youtube know about the origin. In this case, youtube does not allow the video playback and responds with code 204.

This can be resolved by setting a less restrictive referrer policy. You can use ["no-referrer-when-downgrade"](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-no-referrer-when-downgrade).
In django, you can set this with the following variable in `settings.py` file.

```py
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

The above policy states that referrer will be sent as empty when the access protocol is downgraded, else the origin will be sent as referrer (which is acceptable). Given that, ***youtube only allows `https` origins***, for this case it means that if the iframe is embedded in a webpage with https, the referrer will be sent properly and should not cause issues while playing youtube videos through such embeds.

Comment: I've been searching everywhere how to fix my problem and this solved my problem sooooo well. Damn.

Comment: You can also use `referrerpolicy` attribute on `<iframe>` if you don't want to change the referrer policy for whole site

Comment: I did `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"` in settings.py and it worked. :) This setting is also the default for chromium based browsers so less concern on security.

Answer (score 3):

On YouTube there is so called "embed settings" where owner of the video can decide whether or not to allow for it.

Here is an example:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srq643t9/21/)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLsyvDWwjkTqtOmqAiTzzfHspTAztB-udL" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And here you can find more details about this: [YouTube Restrict embedding](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en)

Comment: I will double check and try other videos. Thank you :)

Comment: also fails for this public one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EzdmE4Ewqk

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off of other answers:
In my case I just had to add `referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"` to my iframe and it worked as outlined here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Example with OP code:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that my YouTube video was stuck loading when I embedded it. But if I logged out from my YouTube account, then it started to work. I hope this is a temporary bug YouTube will fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the video was playing fine on my localhost but was showing unavailable when played from the remote server. Turns out it was happening because of this HTTP header: `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer`.

**Removing `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer` HTTP header solved the problem for me.**

Almost took me 15 minutes to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the YouTube embedded video wouldn't normally play on my browser due to YouTube's restriction on localhost. I resolved this by running my HTML/CSS project through Ngrok, which converted my HTTP to HTTPS. Subsequently, when I tried accessing it using the Chrome browser, the embedded video started working.

Note that the embedded video didn't function on the Brave browser due to the presence of an ad blocker.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting an app on localhost and you want a quick way to make your browser *think* you're hosting with a domain, you can edit `/etc/hosts` in linux/mac or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on windows and add a line:

`127.0.0.1 dev.local`

to the end of your /etc/hosts file. Then, if you were accessing your app on `127.0.0.1:3000`, instead use `dev.local:3000`. That way you don't have to pay for a whole server!