# Embedded YouTube video doesn't work on local server

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I saw many questions like this asked on StackOverflow, but none of them had a working answer. My problem is that I can't embed a YouTube video, because a "This video is not available." comes up:

[image: Running on local server]

Here's what I know and have tried so far:

- This error doesn't come up on all videos. From what I've noticed, it's mostly not working on popular music videos.
- Embedding these YouTube videos doesn't work in a local HTML file (`file:///C:/path/to/file.html`) nor when the embedded video is on my local Django server (`12.345.67.89:8080/page`).
- It doesn't work both with Youtube's [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and simply an `<iframe>` copy-pasted from YouTube: [image]
- I tried both `/embed/` and `/watch?v=` as the URL.
- When using the iframe, changing `https://` to `http://` or `//` doesn't work. Taking the `www.` part out doesn't work either.
- Interestingly, it does work when I put the code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L6zom1r/).
- It doesn't work on both Chrome and Firefox.
- There are no errors in the console.
- Accessing the website from my phone (not connecting from my WiFi) or a web proxy doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: When running in Firefox with all extensions disabled on a local server, there's no errors.

Comment: "Interestingly, it does work when I put the code in JSFiddle." The embed in the JSFiddle link doesn't work anymore as of June 21, 2020.

Comment: @bigyihsuan still does for me

Comment: @MarkedasDuplicate it doesn't on my end. If you actually press play, it says "video unavailable". https://i.imgur.com/Z680hpK.png

Comment: In some cases problem may be in Referrer Policy. I got an error with some videos when Referrer Policy header was set to same-origin

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Sergiy Shcherbina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736426/4139786) helped me solve this issue. I was running my web server from a vm and accessing it through my local IP address.

It seems that you need to access your page that contains the embedded youtube player through a host name and NOT an IP address.

**How I solved This for my dev environment**

Before the change, I was accessing my web-page like this: `http://192.168.x.x:3000/video` and i would get 'video unavailable' errors for many videos that were verifiably 'embeddable'.

A Hacky word-around:  I set a hostname for my VM in my hosts file and aliased my IP address to `dev-vm`. [How to edit your host file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)

Now i access the page which has my embedded player like this: `http://dev-vm:3000/video` and now videos that previously gave me a 'video unavailable' error are now playing.

What a bizarre issue. I hope this helps some people who are having a similar issue.

Comment: I think i have the same issue but the embedded videos runs on iOS App

Comment: Same issue happens on mobile Safari too. I was getting it when trying to test my web app from my phone using the direct IP of my `localhost` dev server. So the fix in a MacOS environment is to access the dev server via the `http://<name>.local` method. The computer name is in the Sharing panel of the System Preferences.

Comment: I'm accessing my Django website with : `http://localhost:8000/` but it doesn't work! any idea?

Answer (score 16):

It works on sites with domain and does not work on sites reached by IP adress. Works when using on "localhost" and causes "The video is unavailable" when using "127.0.0.1". This is really strange...

Comment: But why it doesn't even work when directly accessing the embed page by using the YouTube domain like following: https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0

Comment: @SergeyMell While this might not have been useful as an "answer" it was still a VERY  helpful comment/observation. So thanks to Sergiy Shcherbina for adding this "answer"/comment!!

Answer (score 5):

**For some god-forsaken reason**, known only to YouTube's engineers, some videos require an HTTP server to play.

If you're familiar with **npm** and **Node.js**, you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) so you can set up an HTTP server and try it out for yourself.

But please, if you do have the time and willingness, ***send a bug report*** about this issue by following the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4347644?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). This sort of issue should definitely not be happening.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 4):

This is not Youtube APIs fault. Tried running this on my localhost using "`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`" and got it running easily. So, I'm concluding that you don't have a proper local web server. Also, "`file:///C:/path/to/file.html`" will never work because to use any of Google APIs, you need to have access to the internet.

[image]

Comment: only fails for some videos, eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EzdmE4Ewqk

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, I had a similar issue, but the opposite -

My youtube embed was working on my local dev server (`http://localhost:8000`), but when I opened the same page on production (eg `https://example.com`), I'd get "video unavailable" with no useful logs.

I believe I found [the answer on a YouTube Community Support Thread](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/20562339?hl=en&msgid=32097030):

[James Peters 4580](https://support.google.com/profile/32086393):

> Actually found the issue here. The videos that were displaying this on embed had "Copyrighted" music playing in the background. YouTube apparently does not play videos like this while embedded. We had our user remove the audio and re-uploaded the video and everything is working fine now.
>
> Hope this helps somebody.

The video I was embedding had music in the background, so I tried a random video from some youtuber's channel, and that video worked.

If anyone is having this problem (works on localhost, fails on an actual domain / behind https), it's possible that youtube is quietly blocking your embed for DRM reasons.