# How do I modify my host file so I can access my web page through a host name?

Tags: html, windows

[Embedded YouTube video doesn't work on local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969269/embedded-youtube-video-doesnt-work-on-local-server/56419165#comment96255216_54736426)

I looked at this post and it says I have to edit my host file to run an embedded youtube video.
I went on to the tutorial link and opened the host file via notepad, but I'm not sure what to change there (the tutorial does not say). I tried changing my local host address to dev-vm but I think I just made an error.

Comment: You can find how to edit your host file in the link he posted there. https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/ just be aware that you need to open as administrator the notepad

Comment: @SergioSantiago That's the tutorial I used but it never mentions what I need to change inside of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the host file and add a line like this:

`127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com`

And then access your website:

mywebsite.com:5000/

Comment: I have to add a new line? I already have a line that looks like this: ```127.0.0.1 localhost``` I tried changing 'localhost' to 'mywebsite.com' but it did not work.

Comment: Yes you need to add a new line. Make sure you open as administrator, save the file and you are done.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong. I opened notepad as administrator, added the line at the bottom, and pressed save. When I run flask it still runs on the same url and the code still does not work.

Comment: How does your host file looks like?

Comment: Can you please open your terminal and type `ping mywebsite.com`

Comment: Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: The host that you added is working. It must be something else in your application