# Embeded Youtube video doesn't work on chrome

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have this piece of code in HTML file

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i6iBAuwBODA">
        </iframe>
```

And it doesn't work, just saying "Video is unavailable".
what should I do to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Youtube code is not working in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424578/embed-youtube-code-is-not-working-in-html)

Comment: I read it but didn't quite understand how should I replace src value in JSFiddle.Thank you

Comment: So this is a JSFiddle question? Maybe update your tags and question

Comment: You right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the iframe tag directly from youtube that should work. Go to youtube video > share > embed

Answer (score 0):

JS console says:

`local-ntp.js:2084 GET chrome-search://local-ntp/search-suggestions.js net::ERR_FAILED requestAndInsertGoogleResources @ local-ntp.js:2084 init @ local-ntp.js:900 local-ntp.html:1 Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src chrome-search://most-visited/ https://*.google.com/". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback`

idk if that helps

EDIT:

Wait what??? Works fine now.

Comment: Thank you. But can you tell how can I avoid it? Is it any way to do it?

Comment: I think that the video owners/makers disabled the feature... IDK