# video will not insert to html page?

Tags: html, youtube

I tried to insert "All my loving" by the Beatles into my HTML page, using this code:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="753" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TSpiwK5fig0?list=PLDZvge8C5LoxAg8DGVYIkRcH9TaBbTUfa" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

however, I got this error when I tried to run the code:

```
! video unavailable
```

Now I tried this on a lofi video and it worked fine. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You try embed unavailable video - https://www.youtube.com/embed/TSpiwK5fig0

Comment: When a YouTuber uploads a video, they have the option to disable embedding. Musical artists will frequently do this to prevent people from ripping their songs onto other sites easily. It looks like that video can't be embedded, by the uploader's choice

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424578/embed-youtube-code-is-not-working-in-html#55661292), you are facing the problem, most probably because you are running the YouTube embed locally.
So, try using the code online or you can also use [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to test the code (I tested and it was running without problem).

```html
<iframe width="1280" height="753" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TSpiwK5fig0?list=PLDZvge8C5LoxAg8DGVYIkRcH9TaBbTUfa" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```