# Lazy image loading with semantic markup

Tags: html, seo, markup

I have a very image-rich site. To conserve bandwidth for users, I would like to lazy-load images as they enter the view-port. There are [assorted jQuery plugins](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) and similar that accomplish this. This comes at the price of placing the actual image url, not in the `src` attribute but someplace else. This makes the markup less nice, and worse, less intelligible for search engine crawlers.

Is there way to have both lazy image loading and semantic, search-engine-friendly markup?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put `src` of image somewhere else. There are a no. of plugins available. Check the following link http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: That's not correct, the plugin you link to uses a placeholder in `src` and the actual url in the `data-original` attribute.

Comment: Oh I see, Check this link if it could help you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26190/is-this-a-good-approach-to-image-lazy-loading-for-seo

Answer (score 0):

Note that now `<img loading="lazy"` is standardized, so you can just keep `src` as the actual source and everything works perfectly with semantics, more details at: [How do you make images load lazily only when they are in the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321907/how-do-you-make-images-load-lazily-only-when-they-are-in-the-viewport/57389607#57389607)