# Using querySelectorAll(). Is the result returned by the method ordered?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to make a js code that works with multiple pages.
I'm trying to use querySelectorAll() to obtain the elements form the DOM.

I need the elements to be ordered. In order to do that I may use xPath or selectors (I'd prefer to use selectors but xPath is also ok). The problem is:
Are the elements in the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll() ordered against the order that the tags appear in the HTML?

Note: I'd like to add the tag: querySelectorAll

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The returned node list is ordered. A quick test proved it:

```
document.querySelectorAll("body, head")[0]; //Returned [object HTMLHeadElement]
```

Obviously, the `<head>` tag appears before `<body>` in a HTML document. The first element of the NodeList is also a `<head>` element, even if the selector shows `body` before `head.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall:

> The `querySelectorAll()` method on the NodeSelector interface must, when
>   invoked, return a NodeList containing all of the matching Element
>   nodes within the node’s subtrees, **in document order**. If there are no
>   such nodes, the method must return an empty NodeList.

Comment: I already tested with firefox, chrome and Opera. All of them showed them ordered but I just wanted to know if that happens in all browsers.

Comment: That is a CSS selector. The seperation by ',' doesn't mean any order (that part is in the spec in the part about how the selectors select)

Comment: @brunoais Have a look at the linked w3 specification.

Comment: That quote is exactly what I wanted! That answers the question, thank you. (/me still wondering why he didn't find it when he searched)

Comment: @brunoais Google search tips: Add "w3 spec" to your search query if you're looking for an official specification, and "mdn" if you're looking for a reliable source regarding CSS/JavaScript/HTML/...

Comment: +1, but I would move the quote from the spec first, since the fact that one browser implementation at one time returned results in document order doesn't prove much.

Comment: what's "document order"? depth first or breadth first?

Comment: @capr "The term **document order** means a depth-first pre-order traversal of the DOM tree or subtree in question" - https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#document-order