# Get specific Tag elements in body

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all of the following tags inside the body (INPUT, A, and BUTTON) 
is there a way to do that without having to loop through all the tags inside the body using javascript

```
var allInputTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

I was thinking to do something like

```
var inputtags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var atags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('A');
var buttontags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON');

var allTags = inputtags + atags + buttontags;
```

but I think in that way I will not get the elements in the order they appear in the Body.

Comment: `inputtags + atags + buttontags` does not what you think it does.

Comment: How cross-browser do you need to be? [`document.querySelectorAll('input, a, button')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) is a possibility.

Comment: @FelixKling, ya I wasn't sure about that

Comment: @DavidThomas webkit will be fine ...

Comment: Do you need to get the elements in the order that they appear in the document?

Comment: @Guffa, Yes in the exact order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the browser supports [`querySelectorAll` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), you can do :

```
var allTags = document.querySelectorAll('input, a, button');
```

[The elements are returned in document order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203770/using-queryselectorall-is-the-result-returned-by-the-method-ordered). See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) for a list of browsers that support `querySelectorAll`.

In all other browsers, you have to use `getElementsByTagName` but then I think it's going to be very difficult to get the element in order.

You can also consider to use a selector engine, such as [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (the engine used by jQuery). Or if you plan to do complex DOM operations, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) itself.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` has excellent support as far as desktop browsers are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.concat

```
var allTags = inputtags.concat(atags, buttontags);
```

Comment: That won't give you the elements in the order that they appear in the document.