# Order of elements in document.getElementsByClassName() array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm calling

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fastSearch', 'document.forms');
```

in my js code on html.

Will I get the same order of elements everytime I call?

Comment: That's *almost* a dupe -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470813/is-order-of-resulting-array-of-document-queryselectorallinputtype-checkbox/35470956#35470956

Comment: Note: `getElementsByClassName` only accepts a single argument, the second argument you're passing it will be ignored.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you will, on conforming implementations (I don't know of any non-conforming ones), but what [it returns](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) is not an array, it's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#htmlcollection). The results will be in [*tree order*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order)¹ (sometimes called *document order*): top-down, depth-first traversal — which is a fancy way of saying, what it looks like when you look at the markup. :-)

For example, with this document:

```html
<div id="d1" class="a">
    <div id="d2" class="a">
        <div id="d3" class="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="d4" class="a"></div>
</div>
<div id="d5" class="a"></div>
```

...`getElementsByClassName("a")` will reliably list them in order: d1, d2, d3, d4, d5. Try it here:

```js
for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName("a")) {
    console.log(el.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="d1" class="a">
    <div id="d2" class="a">
        <div id="d3" class="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="d4" class="a"></div>
</div>
<div id="d5" class="a"></div>
```

Other notes:

- The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a *live* `HTMLCollection`, which means that if you add, remove, or change elements, the collection you already have is updated. That can be useful and powerful, or surprising, depending on what you're doing with it.
- The related method `querySelectorAll` returns a *snapshot* [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist), e.g., not a live `HTMLCollection`.

Example:

```js
const byClassName = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
const bySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".a");
console.log("Before adding another one:");
console.log("byClassName.length = " + byClassName.length);
console.log("bySelector.length = " + bySelector.length);
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "a"
document.body.appendChild(div);
console.log("AFTER adding another one:");
console.log("byClassName.length = " + byClassName.length);
console.log("bySelector.length = " + bySelector.length);
```

```html
<div id="d1" class="a">
  <div id="d2" class="a">
    <div id="d3" class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="d4" class="a"></div>
</div>
<div id="d5" class="a"></div>
```

---

¹ How do we know that? Because `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` is specified to return *"[the list of elements with class names classNames](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbyclassname),"* which says it returns an `HTMLCollection`; if we look at [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection), we see it's a *"[collection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-collection) of elements,"* and in *that* link we find that the *"...collection then represents a view of the subtree rooted at the collection’s root, containing only nodes that match the given filter. The view is linear. In the absence of specific requirements to the contrary, the nodes within the collection must be sorted in tree order."* Since `getElementsByClassName` doesn't provide specific requirements to the contrary, it's in tree order.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "live HTMLCollection" - explains why the elements disappear from the collection after their className is changed.

Comment: "The results will be in document order" might be a bit optimistic. Though this is clearly stated as a required behavior for `querySelectorAll` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#findelements), I've seen nothing stated as clearly for the `getElements...` conterparts. Does anybody have a pointer to a spec that clarifies that point?

Comment: @nvidot - Thanks for raising that. It is in the spec, but you **really** have to go looking to find it. It took me quite a while to realize where it was. A fair bit of this stuff is indirectly specified via specifying terms (and that's the case here -- "collection"). I've updated the answer to add the citations that should have been there in the first place. Thanks again! (Out of paranoia, I also wrote a [quick-and-**very**-dirty](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ft4nepmg/) test to check it and ran it against Chromium, Firefox, and Safari.)