# Risks of native lazy loading with the HTML loading attribute?

Tags: html, image, lazy-loading

Browsers started recently supporting [native lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59881348/144088) via the `loading` attribute.

However, many image heavy sites like unsplash.com and pexels.com don't use native lazy loading.

Obviously, not all browsers support native lazy loading, but what are the risks of using `loading="lazy"` in addition to other options for lazy loading? That is, if you accept that unsupported browsers won't lazy load images, is there any downside to adding `loading="lazy"` to `img` tags?

Comment: I don't see any. Maybe [this one](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/#is-there-a-downside-to-lazy-loading-images-or-iframes-that-are-within-the-device-viewport) but that is a browser issue which can (and probably will) be solved.

Comment: @str thanks for the reply. could you post as answer if this turns out to be the right answer? thanks for the help!

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks, deleted comment and sent an email.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a bug in chrome, the first browser to support native lazyloading, images that have not yet been loaded will be missing in the printout due to this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875403&q=component:Blink%3ELoader%3ELazyLoad&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).