# Lazy loading images with accessibility and printer support

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, lazy-loading, web-performance

I am looking for a proper way to implement lazy loading of images without harming printability and accessibility, and without introducing layout shift (content jump), preferrably using native `loading=lazy` and a fallback for older browsers. Answers to the question [How lazy loading images using JavaScript works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667631/how-lazy-loading-images-using-javascript-works)
 included various solutions none of which completely satisfy all of these requirements.

An elegant solution should be based on valid and complete html markup, i.e. using `<img src`, `srcset`, `sizes`, `width`, `height`, and `loading` attributes instead of putting the data into `data-` attributes, like the popular javascript libraries [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) and [vanilla-lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload) do. There should be no need to use `<noscript>` elements either.

Due to a [bug in chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875403), the first browser to support native lazyloading, images that have not yet been loaded will be missing in the printed page.

Both javascript libraries mentioned above, require either invalid markup without any `src` attribute at all, or an empty or low quality placeholder (LQIP), while the `src` data is put into `data-src` instead, and `srcset` data put into `data-srcset`, all of which only works with javascript. Is this considered an acceptable or even best practice in 2020, and does this neither harm the site accessibility, cross-device compatibility, nor search engine optimization?

Update:

I tried a workaround for the printing bug using only HTML and CSS `@media print` background images [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ingosteinke/pen/dyXaPqo) . Even if this worked as intended, there would be a necessary css directive for each and every image, which is neither elegant nor generic. Unfortunately there is no way to use media queries inside the `<picture>` element either.

There is another workaround by Houssein Djirdeh at at [lazy-load-with-print-ctl1l4wu1.now.sh](https://lazy-load-with-print-ctl1l4wu1.now.sh) using javascript to change `loading=lazy` to `loading=eager` when a "print" button is clicked. The same function could also be used [onbeforeprint](https://caniuse.com/?search=onbeforeprint).

I made a [codepen using lazysizes](https://codepen.io/ingosteinke/pen/zYKdvGv).

I made another [codepen using vanilla-lazyload](https://codepen.io/ingosteinke/pen/GRjvppQ) .

I thought about forking a javascript solution to make it work using `src` and `srcset`, but this must probably have been tried before, the tradeoff would be that once the lazyloading script starts to act on the image elements, the browser might have already started downloading the source files.

Comment: It is not possible to hit every item on your laundry list and avoid `<noscript>` tags, you need a fallback for when JS fails. Do you want to show us how you have attempted to fix these issues and where you are struggling so we can help as at the moment this is too close to a "how do I" / opinion based question, I think the question has a lot of merit, it just needs a bit more focus.

Comment: @graham-ritchie I added links to examples of partial solutions.

Comment: Right so I suppose the last question is where are you willing to make tradeoffs. For example, the Houssein Djirdeh example only works if you press his print button (at which point he simply waits until all images have loaded until calling `print()`, so if you have a slow connection the page can hang for several seconds or more). Is printing more important than conserving bandwidth for you? Are we assuming people won't print on mobiles? I don't think we can build a perfect solution but if we make certain assumptions I think we can get close.

Comment: One last question, can we assume that this is also server side (as well as client side) as otherwise we will struggle to get the image proportions in order to allocate space to ensure no Layout Shifts occur contributing to CLS

Comment: Thanks @graham-ritchie, I will have a look

Comment: See also this whatwg issue on the problem with using native lazy loading and printing: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6581

Comment: End of 2021 wrap up of the state of printable lazy loading: https://dev.to/ingosteinke/printable-lazy-loading-3hb6

Comment: Update 20 January 2022: printable lazy loading image should have been fixed in the latest Chrome canary, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875403#c36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution for printable lazy loading in 2022 is using the native `loading` attribute.

```
<img loading=lazy>
```

The recommendation to use a custom print button has been obsoleted as [chromium issue 875403](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875403) got fixed.

Prior recommendations included [adding a custom print button](https://lazy-load-with-print-ctl1l4wu1.now.sh) (which did not fix the problem when using the native browser print functionality) or using JavaScript to load images `onBeforePrint` the latter not being considered a good solution, as `loading=lazy`, as a "DOM-only" solution, must not rely on JavaScript.

Beware that, even after the bug fix, some of your users might still visit your site with a buggy browser version.

Answer (score 3):

### Just show me your hideous code, I don't want to read!

**If you don't want to read my ramblings** the final section "Demo" contains a fiddle you can investigate (commented reasonably well in the code) with instructions.

Or there is a [link to the demo on a domain I control here that is easier to test against](https://inhu.co/so/image-concept.php) if you want to use that.

There is also a [version that *nearly* works in IE here](https://inhu.co/so/image-concept-ie.php), for some reason the "preparing for print" screen doesn't disappear before printing but all other functionality works (surprisingly)!

Things to try:

1. Try it at different browser sizes to see the dynamic image requesting
2. try it on a slower connection and check the network tab to see the lazy loading in action and the dynamic change in how lazy loading works depending on connection speed.
3. try pressing CTRL + P when the network connection is slow (without scrolling the page) to see how we load in images not yet in the DOM before printing
4. try loading the page with a slow network connection and then using `FILE > PRINT` to see how we handle images that have not yet loaded in that scenario.

### Version 0.1, proof of concept

So there is still a long way to go, but I thought I would share my solution so far.

It is complex (and flawed) but it is about 90% of what you asked for and potentially a better solution than current image lazy loading.

Also as I am awful at writing clean JS when prototyping an idea. *I can only apologise* to any of you brave enough to try and understand my code at this stage!

**only tested in chrome** - so as you can imagine it might not work in other browsers, especially as grabbing the content of a `<noscript>` tag is notoriously inconsistent. However eventually I hope this will be a production ready solution.

Finally it was too much work to build an API at this stage, so for the image resizing I utilised https://placehold.it - so there are a few lines of redundant code to be removed there.

### Key features / Benefits

#### No wasted image bytes

This solution calculates the **actual size of the image** to be requested. So instead of adding breakpoints in something like a `<picture>` element we actually say we want an image that is 427px wide (for example).

This obviously requires a server-side image resizing solution (which is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer) but the benefits are massive.

First of all if you change all of your breakpoints on the site it doesn't matter, so no updating picture elements everywhere.

Secondly **the difference between a 320px and 400px wide image in terms of kb is over 40%** so picking a "similarly sized" image is not ideal (which is basically what the `<picture>` element does).

Thirdly if people (like me) have massive 4K monitors and a decent connection speed then you can actually serve them a 4K image (although connection speed detection is an improvement I need to make in version 0.2).

Fourthly, what if an image is 50% width of it's parent container at one screen size, 25% width of it's parent container at another, but the container is 60% screen width at one screen size and 80% screen width at another.

Trying to get this right in a `<picture>` element can be frustrating at best. It is even worse if you then decide to change the layout as you have to recalculate all of the width percentages etc.

Finally this saves time when crafting pages / would work well with a CMS as you don't need to teach someone how to set breakpoints on an image (as I have yet to see a CMS handle this better than just setting the breakpoints as if every image is full width on the screen).

#### Minimal Markup (and semantically correct markup)

Although you wanted to not use `<noscript>` and avoid `data` attributes I needed to use both.

However the markup you write / generate is literally an `<img>` element written how you normally would wrapped in a `<noscript>` tag.

Once an image has fully loaded all clutter is removed so your DOM is left with just an `<img>` element.

If you ever want to replace the solution (if browser technology improves etc.) then a simple replace on the `<noscripts>` would get you to a standard HTML markup ready for improving.

#### WebP

Of course this solution requests WebP images if supported (its all about performance!). On the server side you would need to process these accordingly (for example if an image is a PNG with transparency you send that back even if a WebP image is requested).

#### Printing

Oh this was a fun one!

There is nothing we can do if we send a document to print and an image has not loaded yet, I tried all sorts of hacks (such as setting background images) but it just isn't possible (or I am not clever enough to work it out....more likely!)

So what I have done is think of real world scenarios and cover them as gracefully as possible.

1. If the user is on a fast connection we lazy load the images, but we don't wait for scroll to do this. This could mean a bit more load on our servers but I am acting like printing is highly important (second only to speed).
2. If the user is on a slow connection then we use traditional lazy loading.
3. If they press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> we intercept the print command and display a message while the images are loading. This concept is [taken from the example OP gave by Houssein Djirdeh](https://lazy-load-with-print-ctl1l4wu1.now.sh/) but using our lazy loading mechanism.
4. If a user prints using `FILE > PRINT` then we instead display a placeholder for images that have not yet loaded explaining that they need to scroll the page to display the image. (the placeholders are approximately the same size as the image will be).

This is the best compromise I could think of for now.

#### No layout shifts (assuming content to be lazy loaded is off-screen on page load).

Not a 100% perfect solution for this but as "above the fold" content shouldn't be lazy loaded and 95% of page visits start at the top of the page it is a reasonable compromise.

We use a blank SVG (created at the correct proportions "on the fly") using a `data` URI as a placeholder for the image and then swap the `src` when we need to load an image. This avoids network requests and ensures that when the image loads there is no Layout Shift.

This also means the page is semantically correct at all times, no empty `hrefs` etc.

The layout shifts occur if a user has already scrolled the page and then reloads. This is because the `<img>` elements are created via JavaScript (unless JavaScript is disabled in which case the image displays from the `<noscript>` version of the image). So they don't exist in the DOM as it is parsed.

This is avoidable but requires compromises elsewhere so I have taken this as an acceptable hit for now.

#### Works without JavaScript and clean markup

The original markup is simply an image inside a `<noscript>` tag. No custom markup or `data-attributes` etc.

The markup I have gone with is:

```
<noscript class="lazy">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1500x500" alt="an image" width="1500px" height="500px"/>
</noscript>
```

It doesn't get much more standard and clean as that, it doesn't even need the `class="lazy"` if you don't use `<noscript>` tags elsewhere, it is purely for collisions.

You could even omit the `width` and `height` attributes if you didn't care about Layout Shift but as Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) is a [Core Web Vital](https://web.dev/vitals/) I wouldn't recommend it.

### Accessibility

The images are just standard images and `alt` attributes are carried over.

I even added an additional check that if `alt` attributes are empty / missing a big red border is added to the image via a CSS class.

### Issues / compromises

#### Layout Shift if page already scrolled

As mentioned previously if a page is already scrolled then there will be massive layout shifts similar to if a standard image was added to a page without `width` and `height` attributes.

#### Accessibility

Although the image solution itself is accessible the screen that appears when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is not. This is pure laziness on my part and easy to resolve once a more final solution exists.

The lack of Internet Explorer support (see below) however is a big accessibility issue.

#### IE

**UPDATE**
There is a [version that *nearly* works in IE11 here](https://inhu.co/so/image-concept-ie.php). I am investigating if I can get this to work all the way back to IE9.

Also tested in Firefox, Edge and Safari (mobile), seems to work there.

**ORIGINAL**
Although this isn't tested in Firefox, Safari etc. it is easy enough to get to work there if there are issues.

However accessing the content of `<noscript>` tags is notoriously difficult (and impossible in some versions) in IE and other older browsers and as such this solution will probably never work in IE.

This is important when it comes to accessibility as a lot of screen reader users rely on IE as it works well with JAWS.

The solution I have in mind is to use User Agent sniffing on the server and serve different markup and JavaScript, but that is complex and very niche so I am not going to do that within this answer.

#### Checking Latency

I am using a rather crude way of checking latency (to try and guess if someone is on a 3G / 4G connection) of downloading a tiny image twice and measuring the load time.

2 unneeded network requests is not ideal when trying to go for maximum performance (not due to the 100**bytes** I download, but due to the delay on high latency connections before initialising things).

This needs a complete rethink but it will do for now while I work on other bits.

### Demo

Couldn't use an inline fiddle due to character count limitation of 30,000 characters!

So here is the current JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9d5qs6ba/.

Alternatively as mentioned previously the demo can be viewed and tested more easily on a domain I control at https://inhu.co/so/image-concept.php.

I know it isn't the "done thing" linking to your own domains but it is difficult to test printing on a jsfiddle etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Ingo Steinke Before one dwells into answers for the concerns that you have raised, one has to go back and think about why lazy loading came about and for what detriment it solved on initiation as framework of thought. Keyword framework of thought... it is not a solution and I would go on a leaf to say it has never been a solution but framework of thought.
Why we wanted it:

- Minimise unnecessary file fetching from server - this is bandwidth critical if one is running a large user base. So it was the internet version of just in time as in industrial production.
- Legacy browser versions and before async and defer were popularised in JS/HTML, interactivity with the browser window remained hampered until all content was loaded.
- Now broad band as we know it has only been around since the last 6-7 years in real sense of manner and penetration.  We wanted it because we didn't want to encounter no.2 on low bandwidth. To be honest, there was and still is a growing concern and ideology of minifying and zipping JS and CSS files - all because that round trip to server and back should be minimised so that next item in the list could be fetched. Do keep in mind browsers tend to limit simultaneous downloading connections to around 6 at a time per window or active window. There is reasons why Google popularised the 3 second rule. If above were to let run on as it than 3 second rule will fall on its head as if it did not have legs.
- So came along thought frameworks.
- Image as CSS background: This came as it did not mess up the visual aspect of the page. Everything remained as it is in its place and then suddenly became colourful. It was time when web pages seemed to have elastic fit i.e. it was that bag which once filled with air suddenly poped-transformed into jumping castle. This was increasingly become bad idea as front end developer. So fixing height and with of the container then run images as background helped and HTML5 background alignment properties upgraded them self accordingly. There was even variant and still used as in use multiple backgrounds one being loading spiril or low end blured image version on top of which actual intended image was fetched. Since level down bacground would be fetched and populated everywhere in single instance of downloading it created a more pleasing visual and user knew what to expect. worked in printing as well even if intended image did not download.
- Then came JS version of it by hijacking DOM either through data-src, invalid image tags removing src, and what not. only trigger the change when content is scrolled to. Obviously there would be lag but that was either countered through CSS approach implemented in JS or calculating scroll points and triggering event couple of pixel ahead. They all still work on the same premise.

There is one question that begs to be asked and you have touched it in your pretext .... none of it controls or alters browser native functionality. Browser might as will go fetch the item even before your script had anything to do with any thing.

This is the main issue here. BOM does not care and even want to care about what your script is asking to do all it knows if there is a src property fetch the content. None of the solutions have changed that. If we could change that functionality then thought framework would become solution.

I still believe browsers should not change that just for the sake of it and thus never gained tracking in debates. What browsers have done is pre-fetching known as  speculative or look-ahead pre-parser, It is the single biggest improvement in browsers that deserves it credit. Just as we type url in address bar on every chnage of string browser is pre-fetching the content even though I had not typed the whole url. I had specially developed a programme where I grabbed anything that was received at server from these look-ahead pre-parsers. It takes less than second to get response at most times and browsers begin to process it all including images and JS. This was counter the jerky delayed elastic prone display as discussed in No.1 and No.2. It did not reduce the server hit however. The reason why we are doing lazy loading any ways. But some JS workaround gained traction as there was no src  property so pre-parser did not fetch the image and was only done so when user actually sent to the page and events were triggered. Some browser have toyed with the idea of lazy loading them self but let go if it as it did not assume universal consistency in standard.
Universal Standard is simple if there is src property browser will fetch the item no if and buts. Imagine if that was not the case OMG hell would break loose on poor front-end developer.
So deep down what you are raising in debate is the question regarding BOM functionality as I have discussed above. There is no work around for it. In your case both for screen and print version of display. How to make sure images are loaded when print command is sent. Answer is simple for BOM print is after the fact. Fact ebing screen display and before the fact being everything before that at BOM/DOM propagation level. Again you cannot change that.
So you have to make trade off. Trade off would come in the form of another thought framework. rather than assuming everything is print ready make it print ready on user command. There is div that pops up and shows printed version of document and then print from there on. UI could be anything it would only take second or so as majority of the content would be loaded any ways and rest will take short amount of time. CSS rules for print could mighty handy in this respect. You can almost see it in action in may places on the internet.
conclusion as we stand today where we are with BOM functionality bundling the screen display and print display with lazy load is not what lazy lading was intended for thus does not provide any better solution then mere hacks. So you have to create your UI based on your context separating the two, to make it work properly.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS for text edits. Much appreciated.