# Lazy Loading HTML5 picture element

Tags: javascript, html, image, lazy-loading

I have been searching (unsuccessfully) for a reliable method to lazy load images while using the HTML5 spec for `<picture>`. Most solutions/plugins out there currently rely on using `data-` attributes. I could be wrong, but it doesn't seem this method will work in conjunction w/ `<picture>`.

I'm really just looking to be pointed in the right direction. If anyone has a solution that they're currently using, I'd love to see. Thanks!

Here is standard markup per the HTML5 spec:

```html
<picture width="500" height="500">
    <source media="(min-width: 45em)" src="large.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 18em)" src="med.jpg">
    <source src="small.jpg">
    <img src="small.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Can you show your markup, please? By lazy-loading, you mean "*load when in viewport*"? What methods have you found, can you please post one and show how it might be applied to `<pictures>` (and why that would not work)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I made the assumption. By lazy-loading of images, I do mean when they are in the viewport. Most common solution for images I've seen is [Lazy Load plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Comment: Hm, [that plugin is no magic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js). You could easily adapt it to work with `<source>` elements in a picture, instead of using the `src` attribute of an img.

Comment: @MrRay I don't know how browsers parse (or will parse) `<picture>` tag, but most likely appropriate image is loaded during html parsing (like they do currently for `<img>` tag), so the only way to stop it is to use `data-src` attribute instead of `src` in `<source>` tag. But even in this case there are some issues, so in LazyLoadXT we started to use `<br>` tag instead of `<source>`: http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/picture.htm (I don't remember exactly what was the issue with `<source>` tag, but that way didn't work in some browsers, while `<br>` did)

Comment: Thanks @DenisRyabov. Yes, that's exactly the issue I'm trying to resolve. I've seen this plugin - it's the only one to address the issue. Now I understand why it uses the `<br>` tag!

Comment: FYI: the issue with `<source>` tag was that old browsers don't know that this tag is self-closed and generate nested DOM like `<picture><source><source><source></source></source></source></picture>`, and such a structure breaks work of the plugins. Maybe it's possible to fix this issue, but it was much simple to just replace `<source>` by `<br>` (that is supported by all browsers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone still interested...
After revisiting this issue, I came across a fairly new script called, [Lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). It's actually quite versatile, but more importantly it allows me to do lazy loading of images while utilizing the HTML5 markup as described in the OP.

Much thanks to the creator of this script, [@aFarkas](https://github.com/aFarkas).

Answer (score 86):

<s>It's February 2020 now and I'm pleased to report that [Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge (the Chromium-based Edge), and Mozilla Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr) all support the new `loading="lazy"` attribute. The only modern browser hold-out is Apple's Safari (both iOS Safari and macOS Safari) [but they've recently finished adding it to Safari's codebase](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200764), so I expect it will be released sometime this year.</s>

It's February 2024 now and I'm pleased to report that **[all web-browsers today have supported `<img loading="lazy" />` since January 2022](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr)**.

---

The `loading="lazy"` attribute is only for the `<img />` element (and not `<picture>`) but remember that the `<picture>` element does not represent the actual *replaced-content*, the `<img />` element does (i.e. the image that users see is always rendered by the `<img />` element, the `<picture>` element just means that the browser can change the `<img src="" />` attribute. [From the HTML5 spec as of February 2020](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#htmlpictureelement) (emphasis mine):

> The `picture` element is somewhat different from the similar-looking `video` and `audio` elements. While all of them contain `source` elements, the `source` element's `src` attribute has no meaning when the element is nested within a `picture` element, and the resource selection algorithm is different. **Also, the `picture` element itself does not display anything; it merely provides a context for its contained `img` element that enables it to choose from multiple URLs**.

So doing this should *just work*:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 45em)" srcset="large.jpg" />
    <source media="(min-width: 18em)" srcset="med.jpg" />
    <source src="small.jpg" />
    <img src="small.jpg" alt="Photo of a turboencabulator" loading="lazy" />
</picture>
```

---

Note that [the `<picture>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) does not have any `width` or `height` attribute of its own; instead the `width` and `height` attributes should be applied to the child `<source>` and `<img>` elements:

> #### [4.8.17 Dimension attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#dom-dim-width)
>
> The `width` and `height` attributes on `img`, `iframe`, `embed`, `object`, `video`, `source` when the parent is a `picture` element [...] may be specified to give the dimensions of the visual content of the element (the width and height respectively, relative to the nominal direction of the output medium), in CSS pixels.
>
> [...]
>
> The two attributes must be omitted if the resource in question does not have both an intrinsic width and an intrinsic height.

So if you want all `<source>` images to be rendered as `500px` by `500px` then apply the size to the `<img>` element only (and don't forget the `alt=""` text for vision-impaired users, [it's even a legal requirement in many cases](https://www.w3.org/WAI/policies/)):

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 45em)" srcset="large.jpg" />
    <source media="(min-width: 18em)" srcset="med.jpg" />
    <source src="small.jpg" />
    <img src="small.jpg" alt="Photo of a turboencabulator" loading="lazy" width="500" height="500" />
</picture>
```

Comment: @KyleMit thanks, I was juggling with multiple issues, I meant to have linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321907/how-do-you-make-images-load-lazily-only-when-they-are-in-the-viewport

Comment: Does this mean that attributes `width` and `height` also could be in the `img`?

Answer (score 6):

Working example of lazy loading images using the **picture** element and **intersection observer** tested in Chrome and Firefox. Safari doesn't support intersection observer so the images are loaded immediately, and IE11 doesn't support the  element so we fallback to the default **img**

The media queries in the media attr are arbitrary and can be set to suit.

The width threshold set is 960px - try a reload above and below this width to see either the medium(-m) or large(-l) variation of the image being downloaded when the image is scrolled into the viewport.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sean_pwc/pen/qLKGLQ)**

```
<!-- Load images above the fold normally -->
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/city-m.jpg" media="(max-width: 960px)">
  <source srcset="img/city-l.jpg" media="(min-width: 961px)">
  <img class="fade-in" src="img/city-l.jpg" alt="city"/>
</picture>

<picture>
  <source srcset="img/forest-m.jpg" media="(max-width: 960px)">
  <source srcset="img/forest-l.jpg" media="(min-width: 961px)">
  <img class="fade-in" src="img/forest-l.jpg" alt="forest"/>
</picture>

<!-- Lazy load images below the fold -->
<picture class="lazy">
  <source data-srcset="img/river-m.jpg" media="(max-width: 960px)">
  <source data-srcset="img/river-l.jpg" media="(min-width: 961px)">
  <img data-srcset="img/river-l.jpg" alt="river"/>
</picture>

<picture class="lazy">
  <source data-srcset="img/desert-m.jpg" media="(max-width: 960px)">
  <source data-srcset="img/desert-l.jpg" media="(min-width: 961px)">
  <img data-srcset="img/desert-l.jpg" alt="desert"/>
</picture>
```

and the JS:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var lazyImages =[].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".lazy > source")
   )

   if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
      let lazyImageObserver = 
       new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
          entries.forEach(function(entry) {
           if (entry.isIntersecting) {      
              let lazyImage = entry.target;
              lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
              lazyImage.nextElementSibling.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
              lazyImage.nextElementSibling.classList.add('fade-in');
              lazyImage.parentElement.classList.remove("lazy");
             lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
            }
         });
        });

      lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
       lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
      });
   } else {
     // Not supported, load all images immediately
    lazyImages.forEach(function(image){
        image.nextElementSibling.src = image.nextElementSibling.dataset.srcset;
      });
    }
  });
```

One last thought is that if you change the screen width back and forth, the image files are repeatedly downloaded again. If I could tie the above method in to a cache check then this would be golden...

Answer (score 4):

On web.dev Google advices that picture tags can be loaded lazy.
https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/

> Images that are defined using the  element can also be lazy-loaded:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="large.jpg 1x, larger.jpg 2x">
  <img src="photo.jpg" loading="lazy">
</picture>
```

> Although a browser will decide which image to load from any of the  elements, the loading attribute only needs to be included to the fallback  element.