# How to call a onload callback on webp images load?

Tags: javascript, webp, avif

As we know, we could call a `onLoad` callback on `img` elements for images load.
like what I did for it:

```js
var i = new Image();
if (crossOrigin) i.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;

i.onload = function () {
  decode && i.decode ? i.decode().then(resolve)["catch"](reject) : resolve();
};

i.onerror = reject;
i.src = src;
```

But if I use `avif` or `webp` formats with `picture` tag, how could I wait for load event?
sth like:

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="img/photo.avif" type="image/avif">
    <source srcset="img/photo.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="Description of Photo">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches.  You can use a library or you could use the IntersectionObserver API and add the needed feature.

Rather than repeating things, the SO post here has some inputs which you may adopt as needed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092875/34644