# Lazy Load for CSS Images

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following lazy load function which works for <img>.

```html
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          var lazyloadImages;    

          if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
            lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");
            var imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
              entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                  var image = entry.target;
                  image.src = image.dataset.src;
                  image.classList.remove("lazy");
                  imageObserver.unobserve(image);
                }
              });
            });

            lazyloadImages.forEach(function(image) {
              imageObserver.observe(image);
            });
          } else {  
            var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
            lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");
            
            function lazyload () {
              if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
              }    

              lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
                lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
                    if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
                      img.src = img.dataset.src;
                      img.classList.remove('lazy');
                    }
                });
                if(lazyloadImages.length == 0) { 
                  document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
                  window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
                  window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
                }
              }, 20);
            }

            document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
            window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
            window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
          }
        })
    </script>
```

The function isn't mine and I need to know how to modify it to work for the next example which load images from CSS:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 photo" style="padding: 2.5px">
    <span onclick="window.location.href=\''.$link.'\';" 
        class="thumbnail" 
        role="img" 
        style="background-image: url(\''.$image.'\'); cursor: pointer; margin: 0; margin-top: 5px;" 
        aria-label="' . $row["topic_title"] . '"
        title="'.$row['topic_title'].'">
    </span>
    
    <center>
        <p class="name" style="margin 0 2px; color: white; margin-top: 5px;">
            <a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$row['topic_title'].'">' . $title . '</a>
        </p>
    </center>
</div>
```

On a page with 24 gifs, the page loads relatively slow and I'd like to change that.
I could load the images as normal using <img>, but I want the page to be more dynamic because using span I have different temathic.

Here is how I managed to do the script and it works correctly.
Hope someone will find it useful.

```html
if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    var image = entry.target;
    image.src = image.dataset.src;      
    var imageUrl = "url" + "(" + "'" + image.src + "')";
    entry.target.style.backgroundImage = imageUrl;
    image.classList.remove("lazy");
    imageObserver.unobserve(image);
}
```

Comment: Side-note: for `<img />` you don't need any scripts - just use `loading="lazy"` - all major browsers added support for it about 1-2 years ago, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405256/159145

Answer (score 0):

> On a page with 24 gifs, the page loads relatively slow and I'd like to
> change that.

Images in general are really heavy on websites. That's most likely whats slowing the site down. If your website needs that many GIFs I would firstly look at compression techniques. Search for GIF to WebP converters and file compressors ([ImageAlpha](https://pngmini.com/), [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac), [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to name a few).

Good luck!