# whats the fastest way to load images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, reactjs

Lets say I have an ecommerce site with 15,000 image elements to insert into the html, whats the most efficient method using javascript to increase efficiency and user experience?

Comment: more to the point, why?

Comment: Wow I would be curious to understand why you need so many images in a single page?

Comment: Create a sprite for all CSS related images

Comment: How about this - don't load 15,000 images onto a sigle page.

Comment: Either a huge sprite or defer load them when needed.
Also, pagination.

Comment: Is the end-user interested in seeing all 15000 images?

Comment: Do you really want to display 15.000 images on one page? Or do you want to first display a limited number of images? Please elaborate.

Comment: no i dont need 15000 on one page, i just want to know the fastest way to load images only when they are in the viewport

Comment: Ok so it sounds more like you have a base of 15k items and you are asking for a website architecture to enable visitors browsing through them? JavaScript may be just a part of the answer in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the images only when they are in the view port.

This question tells you how:

[How do you make images load only when they are in the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321907/how-do-you-make-images-load-only-when-they-are-in-the-viewport)

Answer (score 0):

Preload the images and use the cdn to host your images.

You can use something like https://github.com/thinkpixellab/PxLoader to preload the images.