# Find followers of an element in a certain scope, which aren't siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all following elements of an element I choose. They don't necessarily have to be direct siblings of my chosen Element, so `.nextAll()` won't work.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="scope">
    <div> <a href="1">1</a> </div>
    <div> <a href="2">2</a> </div>
    <div> <a href="3">3</a> </div>
    <div> <a href="4">4</a> </div>
</div>

<a href="x">NOT THIS</a>
```

My element is `a[href="2"]`, so I want to select `a[href="3"]` and `a[href="4"]`, but *not* `a[href="x"]` because it's not in my scope.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827482/jquery-find-next-prev-elements-of-a-certain-class-but-not-necessarily-siblings), but it only fetches one follower, but I need all of them.

I just wrote this, which works great, but it seems odd to me and I am sure that there have to be better solutions than this one:

```
var $two = $('a[href="2"]');

var selection = [];

var comes_after_2 = false;
$two.closest('.scope').find('a').each(function(){
    console.log(this, $two.get(0));
    if(comes_after_2){
        selection.push(this);
    }
    if(this == $two.get(0)){
        comes_after_2 = true;
    }
});

$(selection).css('background', 'red');
```

Here is a Fiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/mnff40fy/1/

Please feel free to modify it, if there's a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: You said they don't have to be siblings, but they are in your example. Can you show an example where they're not siblings?

Comment: I can't control the nesting of the elements, it is arbitrary. There will be just imagine that `a[href="2"]` could be nested more than the rest.

Comment: I was just asking for a better example, to show the different cases, as I wasn't sure that I understood you.

Comment: But you got me right. :) Anyway - here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnff40fy/4/ With "not being siblings" I meant that they not necessarily have to be on the same level in the DOM-tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $all_a = $two.closest('.scope').find('a');
// Get the position of the selected element within the set
var a_index = $all_a.index($two);
// Select all the remaining elements in the set
var $followers = $all_a.slice(a_index+1);
$followers.css('background', 'red');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mnff40fy/3/)

Comment: Never knew about slice, nice!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6g98ck6/)

I changed the markup a little to have the `href='#'` so you could click each one and see how the other elements respond.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('a').css('background', 'none');    
    var scopeDiv = $(this).closest('div.scope');
    var thisIndex = $(scopeDiv).find('a').index(this);
    $(scopeDiv).find('a').not(this).each(function(index){
       if(index >= thisIndex)
           $(this).css('background', 'red');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use .nextAll() if you modify it a bit.

In your `html` code, you placed the `a` elements as children of the `div` tags.  In order to incorporate `.nextAll()` you should select for the wrapper `div` elements and then call `.nextAll()` and then select for the children `a` elements.

Here is what I mean.

`html`

```
<div class="scope">
    <div>
        <a href="1">1</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Start Here -->
    <div class="start">
        <a href="2">2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="3">3</a>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a href="4">4</a>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="x">NOT THIS</a>
```

`js`

```
$( '.start' ).nextAll().children( 'a' ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

Explanation:

- I select the wrapper div with `$( '.start' )`
- I then select all of its subsequent siblings with `.nextAll()`
- Of those siblings, I select their children that match 'a'
- I apply the css

And here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnff40fy/2/)

Comment: This won't work, because I only have given a reference to `a[href="2"]`. I can't control if my "start" is nested deeper or as a parent of my wanted selection, sorry!