# How can I get the "first element X after the element Y" with CSS selectors?

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

In a Java application, imagine I have this somewhere in a huge HTML code:

```
<h2>
   <b>
      This
   </b>
</h2>

<h1>
</h1>
```

So imagine I want to get the first element `h1` after the element `b`. I've tried some CSS selectors through the JSoup library but found nothing useful. The greatest problem here is: **They are not siblings**. I don't know if the `b` element is or is not a child of a different parent.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Looking for a class, instead of an `h1`, but the logic and problem are the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827482/jquery-find-next-prev-elements-of-a-certain-class-but-not-necessarily-siblings

Comment: are you trying to target it for a js script or in a css sheet?

Comment: I don't typically recommend libraries since I'm a firm believer in vanilla js, but, jQuey is really, really useful for DOM traversal.

Comment: Your question is unclear: Are you trying to: 1) Use just CSS, 2) Use JavaScript's DOM API (possibly with CSS selectors), or 3) Use JSoup (not in a browser)?

Comment: Sorry for not letting it clear. I want to achieve it through CSS,JS or JSOUP, specifically.

Comment: That's still not clear: What environment are you using? A browser? A Java application? What? JSoup wouldn't be relevant to a browser.

Comment: Not possible with CSS for the reason bolded in the question.

Comment: thuper unclear.  those are such different use cases...

Comment: It's a Java application, but Jsoup has a method that searches the HTML document with CSS selectors.

Comment: Please don't confuse Java with JavaScript.

Comment: Your question was originally tagged [javascript] instead of [java].

Comment: Anyway, are you able to identify this `b` element? If so, a starting point in Java code would be useful.

Comment: I see now why this question was deemed unclear (and why you originally tagged your question [javascript]) - you state that you want to achieve this through either JS, CSS or jsoup, but jsoup can't execute JavaScript or apply CSS, so what is not clear (at least to me anyway) is how exactly you intend to do this in JS or CSS.

Comment: Sorry, then. Yes, I'm able to find the B element (in the real world, it has an ID). I mean, I can do this in Java with a linear search through the HTML document, but I wanted to keep it more simple manipulating it as a DOM tree.

Comment: JSoup has a "Select" method that uses JS/CSS selectors to search through the document...that's why any of the solutions would fit. Sorry for no letting it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it purely with CSS selectors, you'll have some logic you'll have to perform in your code using JSoup.

This algorithm would work on a browser as well as a JSoup document. Basically, starting from the `b` element, here's how you find the `h1`:

1. Set `current` to `b`.
2. While `current` is not `null`:

   1. Set `sibling` to `current`'s *next element sibling* (in JSoup, that would be the [`nextElementSibling` *method*](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling()); in any vaguely modern browser, it's the `nextElementSibling` *property*.
   2. While `sibling` is not `null`:

      1. If `sibling` is an `h1`, you're done
      2. Otherwise, set `sibling` to `sibling`'s next element sibling and continue this sibling loop (the "while `sibling` is not `null`")
   3. (`sibling` is `null`) Set `current` to `current`'s parent node. In JSoup, that would be the [`parent` *method*](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#parent()). In a browser, it would be the  `parentNode` *property*.
   4. If `current` is not `null`, continue this parent loop (the "while `current` is not `null`").
   5. There was no following `h1`.

Comment: Thanks! But does this solutions finds "nephews"? It seems that, since I have a current element, I can only find elements that are at the same level it is or any above, but not any under.

Comment: @MrGuliarte: This finds any *following* nephews, yes.