# Get ID of Previous Table in the DOM issue

Tags: jquery, dom, element

When i use the fn below it returns the current table as previous..

I "tweaked" the index in the slice to get the results I was looking for. This is a hack and I am looking for explanation/answer if there is something I am missing.

Each tables is nested in a div or 2.  But using the selector I would assume the previous would be the previous of the selector specified.

hack:
             ? $all.slice(0, $all.index(this)**-10**).reverse()
             : $all.slice($all.index(this) **+ 2**)

original func:

```
$.fn.reverse = function () {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};

// create two new functions: prevALL and nextALL.
$.each(['prev', 'next'], function (unusedIndex, name) {
    $.fn[name + 'ALL'] = function (matchExpr) {
        // get all the elements in the body, including the body. 
        var $all = $('body').find('*').andSelf();

        // slice the $all object according to which way we're looking 
        $all = (name == 'prev')
             ? $all.slice(0, $all.index(this)).reverse()
             : $all.slice($all.index(this) + 1)
        ;
        // filter the matches if specified 
        if (matchExpr) $all = $all.filter(matchExpr);
        return $all;
    };
});
```

elements: these are looped, **I am trying to navigate from one table to the next using up, down, left right arrow keys.. and need to be able to get the ID of the previous & next table**

```
                    "<div id='divOuter" + div.divCode + "' class='BoxOuterDiv' >"
                    + " <div id='div" + div.divCode + "' class='BoxDiv' >"
                    + "         <table class='grid' id='" + div.divCode + "' width='100%'>"
                    + "             <tr>"
                    + "                 <td class='col0' width='125px' nowrap='nowrap'>"
                    + "                     <span id='spn0" + div.divCode + "' class='rgCollapse' onclick='Collapse(this)'>&nbsp&nbsp</span>"
                    + "                     Division: " + div.divCode
                    + "                 </td>"
                    + "                 <td class='col1' width='5%' style='padding-left:15px' nowrap='nowrap'>"
                    + "                     Description: "
                    + "                 </td>"
                    + "                 <td class='col2' width='40%' nowrap='nowrap'>"
                    + "                     <input class='grid' type='text' id='dvDesc" + div.divCode + "' value='" + div.divDesc + "' style='width: 400px' maxlength='60' />"
                    + "                 </td>"
                    + "                 <td class='col3' width='50%' align='right' nowrap='nowrap'>"
                    + "                     <input type='button' id='btnDv" + div.divCode + "' value='Add Business Unit' style='align:right' onclick='AddMfRow(this);' />"
                    + "                 </td>"
                    + "             </tr>"
                    + "         </table>"
                    + " </div>"
                    + "<div id='divWrapper" + div.divCode + "'>"
```

Credit to Author:
[jQuery to find all previous elements that match an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322912/jquery-to-find-all-previous-elements-that-match-an-expression)

Another question.. This blows up in IE! any idea why??

```
$.fn.reverse = function () {
return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
```

};

// create two new functions: prevALL and nextALL.
$.each(['prev', 'next'], function (unusedIndex, name) {
    $.fn[name + 'ALL'] = function (matchExpr) {
        // get all the elements in the body, including the body. 
        var $all = $('body').find('*').andSelf();

```
    // slice the $all object according to which way we're looking 
    $all = (name == 'prev')
         ? $all.slice(0, $all.index(this)-10).reverse()
         : $all.slice($all.index(this) + 2)
    ;

    // filter the matches if specified 
    if (matchExpr) $all = $all.filter(matchExpr);
    return $all;
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("table").parent("#divOuter").prev("#divOuter").find("table"); //up one

$("table").parent("#divOuter").next("#divOuter").find("table"); //down one
```

also i would change your ids to classes if you are looping as only 1 unique id is allowed per page.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for a more generic way to do this. the id's are unique.. its a concatenation id='div" + divCode + "'