# How to append content to an element after a certain class/element

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I am working with a calendar and need to append every day after the class 'fc-today'.

Currently, I am able to append all of the elements with the class 'fc-date' using the script below:

```
var i = 0;
$('.fc-date').each(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).append('<p class="count">' + i + '</p>');         
});
```

The problem with this is that it appends the elements before 'fc-date'. Would anyone be able to help me to make it so that the append only occurs to elements after 'fc-date'.

*NOTE: It would be preferable if the solution was able to work on all 'fc-date' elements across multiple parents.

Any advice or assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:

How the HTML currently looks:

```
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fc-today">
     <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">5</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i want it to look:

```
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fc-today">
     <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fc-date">
        <p class="count">3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us the original html, the html that results from running this script, and the html that you want to end up with?

Comment: With `$(this).append` you are appending inside the fc-date not after or before

Comment: [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

Comment: use `after()` function.

Comment: I think he wants to append that `<p>` element to all of the 'fc-date' elements that show up _after_ 'fc-today'. Is that correct?

Comment: @ChrisForrence maybe but question is not clear enough

Comment: That is correct @ChrisForrence, apologies for not being clear enough A.Wolff

Comment: @MaverickHusker then show how looks your HTML the selector depends on that

Comment: I'll add in the HTML before and after now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an structure like this:

```
<div class="fc-date">Day</div>
<div class="fc-date">Day</div>
<div class="fc-today">Day</div>
<div class="fc-date">Day</div>
<div class="fc-date">Day</div>
```

Then use `nextAll()` like this:

```
$('.fc-today').nextAll('.fc-date').each(function(i){
    $(this).append('<span class="count">' + i + '</span>');
})
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkPtv/)**

---

*Edit : Found solution in another post to your actual Markup*

This problem is more common and searching a little with the right words I found this answer here on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/324159/2887133

Here the user makes an excellent function that solves your problem traversing all levels of the DOM

Here is the Fiddle aplying his answer **http://jsfiddle.net/SkPtv/2/**.

I've upvoted his answer please upvote that too since is the real answer to your problem.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be exactly what I need but when I try to implement it doesn't work for me. It should be enough to work with though so thanks.

Comment: @MaverickHusker this doesn't work with your actual markup I post it before you edit the post.

Comment: Ah ok, would you be able to help me with one that works with the posted markup?

Comment: @MaverickHusker found an answer check the Edit

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I had to change it slightly to get it to work, I removed the following lines:
$.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};

and then wrapped the rest in a function.

Thanks again.
Will upvote your answer and the answer in the thread you linked to when I have the 15 reputation required.

Comment: @MaverickHusker Np mate at the end all credit is for him :) glad to help you found the answer ... I learn too with this XD

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `after()` method and `append()` will append data inside the selector not after or before the selector

```
var i = 0;
$('.fc-date').each(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).after('<p class="count">' + i + '</p>');         
});
```

You can simplify it as follows

```
$('.fc-date').each(function(i){
    $(this).after('<p class="count">' + i + '</p>');         
});
```

**Documentation :**[**https://api.jquery.com/after/‎**](https://api.jquery.com/after/%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUdFv/)

**HTML**

```
<p id="first">something</p>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('#first').after().append('<p>second</p>');
```

Comment: i dont get it, please explain. I might get some new knowledge too :)

Comment: `$('#first').after().append('<p>second</p>');` is effectively the same as `$('#first').append('<p>second</p>');`. Your call to `after()` isn't adding any content, so it isn't doing anything.

Comment: no, its doing its thing. You can inspect the markup thats being produced from the fiddle. because `append()` adds the content inside the target element.

Comment: It's just appending , there is no need of `after()` in your code , even removed that it will give same output.

Comment: @rockStar The `append()` is doing it's thing. The `after()` isn't doing anything. You'll get the same result without it.

Answer (score -1):

`.insertAfter()` or `.after` should do the trick.