# NextAll for entire page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to find a function that selects all element matching AFTER the clicked one on the entire page. Regardless of what container they are in. nextAll only gives the siblings. I need when second is clicked, every DIV with the class family except for the ones with the text First and Second in them to get assigned the class after.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>nextAll demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #abc;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  div.after {
    border-color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="family" >First</div>
<div class="family" >Second</div>
<div>sibling<div class="family">child</div></div>
<div class="family">sibling</div>
<div class="family">sibling</div>
<script>

$('div.family').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.family').addClass( "after" );
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery to find all previous elements that match an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322912/jquery-to-find-all-previous-elements-that-match-an-expression)

Comment: Check the answer on the duplicate It provides a function to evaluate better withe nextall and prevall try that

Comment: Thank you, that was a perfect solution. I had trouble finding that with the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of `$.fn.filter`

```
var txts = ["First", "Second"];
$('div.family').click(function(){
    $('.family').filter(function(){
      return txts.indexOf($(this).text().trim()) == -1
    }).addClass( "after" );
});
```

What we do is make use of an array which contain texts which shouldn't be in the div and then make use of `Array.indexOf` to see if it's not available.

Comment: @Snuur glad to have helped :) Make sure you mark the answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: Yes for this one its the only answer but I have actually used the answer given in the duplicate question listed above. So not sure what to do here.

Comment: @Snuur accepting answer means that you approve the answer and it helped you. The acceptance mark also helps future visitors. The rest is for you to decide :)