# jQuery find the previous elements label in .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with input items.  What I have done is get the label for each input element in my form.  I have done this already but the trouble I am having is this...for every input element that does NOT have a label I want to set their label as the previous label.  I did a mock up of what I am looking for in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4sdfvy/).

```
myItems.each(function(){
    label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').text();

    if(label.length <= 0){
      // code I'm looking for goes here   
    }
});
```

UPDATE: I updated the JSFiddle to show a true represenstion of what I am trying to accomplish and the attempt with .prev().  [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4sdfvy/5/)

Comment: You forgot `inquiry-ref_check` in your selector : `label = $('label[for=inquiry-ref_check"' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').text();`

Comment: seems like you are looking for either closest or parents method of the jquery object that would allow you to browse for the first <label> found in the ancestors of your input in the DOM

Comment: @JeremyThille I want to get all, this is only one of the many input elements.

Comment: @Louis I tried both but didn't get the intended result.

Comment: Can you update both your question and the jsfiddle with what you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)?

Comment: @Louis I updated as requested.

Comment: @nem I updated the request to show my .prev() attempt.

Comment: There is a similar answer. You'd need to find the last label in prevALL (the selector defined by poster).  http://stackoverflow.com/a/324159/4677585

Comment: You're talking about `label` for `input` or `UL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution without using `jQuery.prev()`, as you don't know if the previous one has a label (maybe you need the one before the prev()).

```
var label = '';
var myItems = $('#panel').find('input');
var previousLabel;
myItems.each(function(){
label = $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').text();

if(label.length <= 0) {
    // ensure that a previous label exists
    if (typeof(previousLabel) != 'undefined')
    {
        label = previousLabel;

        // Here you can use your previous label
    }
} else {
    previousLabel = label;
}
});
```

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4sdfvy/6/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it would be something like this:

```
var label, myItems = $('#panel input');

myItems.each(function(i, e){
    var l = $('[for="'+e.id+'"]');
    label = l.length ? l : label;
    l.length || $(e).before(label.clone().attr('for', e.id));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/86ff4nub/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, had to amend the HTML a little, will this work for you?

```
var myItems = $('#panel').find('input');
var label;

myItems.each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().find('label').length){
        label = $(this).parent().find('label');
    } else {
        var newLabel = document.createElement('label');
        newLabel.innerHTML = label.html();
        $(this).parent().prepend(newLabel);
    }        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mp4sdfvy/10/